# How to make a div span 100% of the page even when scrolling to the right

Tags: html, css

This has probably been answered before somewhere, but I cant find a good solution. I want to create a header, which behaves like a div which is  position:absolute in the sense that it will stay at the top of the page when one scrolls down. Although, I would also like the user to be able to scroll right and left and have the header maintain its 100% width of the view port. Right now, with position absolute there becomes a white space to the right of the header as seen in the image. How can I create a header which maintains 100% width when scrolling right to left, but also stays at the top of the page when scrolling down using only css?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navbar: make it `position:fixed`

And width of your content as 300%
As shown in fiddle.

**EDIT**

By adding JQuery, I was able to get the desired output.

1. You are able to scroll the `content`, left and right keeping the navbar at it's place.
2. When you scroll vertical, navbar disappears. Just like a regular webpage.

---

```js
$(window).scroll({
    previousTop: 0
  },
  function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentTop <= this.previousTop) {
      $(".header").show();
    } else {
      $(".header").hide();
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 700px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1 style="color:white">Scroll Right</h1>
    <h1 style="color:red; background-color:yellow; left:100%;">Scroll Right</h1>
    <h1 style="color:gree; left:200%;">Scroll Right</h1>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Saw your comment, let me try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hopgin for a non javascript solution, but maybe its not possible. Not using jquery, using angular, but I am pretty sure I can accomplish the same with a listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed` to fix your header to the top of the page
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Yes but, then that will make the the header follow with the user when they scroll down. I dont want that. Is there a way to do it so it stays at the top?